# javac не выдает ошибок

Tags: java, linux, ubuntu, компилятор

Решаю пример из учебника. Создал файл Puzzle4.java, в нем main класс. Пытаюсь скомпилировать (там скорее всего ошибки в коде, хотел увидеть что напишет компилятор).

```
$ ls
Mix4.class  Mix4.java  Puzzle4.java  README.md  test.txt
$ javac Puzzle4.java
$ ls
Mix4.class  Mix4.java  Puzzle4.java  README.md  test.txt
```

Ни каких ошибок в терминал не выводилось. В папке есть другой пример Mix4.java, который успешно скомпилировался и запускается. Версии javac и java одинаковые:

```
$ java -version
java version "1.8.0_101"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_101-b13)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.101-b13, mixed mode)
$ javac -version
javac 1.8.0_101
```

Что мне надо сделать, чтобы компилятор выводил информацию об ошибках в коде?

Comment: А с чего вы взяли, что там ошибки в коде, если компилятор вам ничего не выдал? Если там, к примеру, `RuntimeException`, то компилятор вам ничего и не выдаст. только запускать надо

Comment: Приведите код, на котором компилятор должен, по вашему мнению, выдавать ошибку.

Comment: помог @GreyGoblin, открыл файл, а там пусто. Как обычно слона не разглядел (не сохранил код в файле).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Спасибо @GreyGoblin, только после его просьбы показать код понял, что не сохранил файл и он был пустой. После редактирования файла компилятор выдает ошибки, но это мне и надо было, так что вопрос решен.